# how to convert return type to void using Redux types?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I would like to derive the types for props a react component based on the action types. Since action types always return action object and dispatched props wouldn't have a return type, how can we get the correct type for dispatched props as in the expected type?

```
export type Action =
  ({ type: 'PING', arg: number })

const ping = (arg: number): Action => ({
  type: 'PING', arg
})

interface Props {
  ping: typeof ping;
}

const PingTestComponent: React.SFC<Props> = ({ping}) => {
  return (
    <Button onPress={() => ping(123)} title="ping"/>
  );
};

export const PingTest = connect(
  null,
  ({ ping: ping })
)(PingTestComponent);
```

I was expecting the dispatched props resolved types to be

**Expected**

```
 interface Props {
   ping: (arg: number) => void
}
```

Comment: As I understand, redux's dispatch props won't have return type as the state updates are obtained from `state` directly instead of the return value from the dispatch props.

Comment: You can log return value of `ping(123)` and you'll see `{ type: 'PING', arg: 123 }`. I mean "connected" `ping`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually props connected to action creators will have the same return type and not `void`.

Anyway, this is how you can change return type of a function:

```
declare function foo(bar: string, baz: boolean): { type: 'A' };

type WithReturnVoid<T extends (...arg) => any> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => void;

type VoidFoo = WithReturnVoid<typeof foo>; // (bar: string, baz: boolean) => void
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20function%20foo(bar%3A%20string%2C%20baz%3A%20boolean)%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20'A'%20%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20WithReturnVoid%3CT%20extends%20(...arg)%20%3D%3E%20any%3E%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20Parameters%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%0Atype%20VoidFoo%20%3D%20WithReturnVoid%3Ctypeof%20foo%3E%3B)

`Parameters` is builtin utility that allows to get the type of function arguments.

So in your example it will be:

```
interface Props {
  ping: WithReturnVoid<typeof ping>;
}
```